# Mismatch when duplicating lua table

Tags: lua, nested, compare, hex, lua-table

I'm writing a game using Lua and Love2d but I've hit a snag when dealing with nested tables.

I have a function that runs through a table containing numbers corresponding to walls, buttons, etc. and prints colored blocks based on the keys. An example of one of these tables would look like this:

```
map = {
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
    { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 } 
    { 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1 } 
    { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 } 
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 } 
}
```

This works fine when rendered. However when I attempt to create this same table using a function that reads this data from a text file looking like this:

```
    111111111
    100000001 
    101120001 
    100000001 
    111111111
```

It creates a table that *seems* identical but it simply doesn't work when I try to render it.

So I tried debugging using a bit of code that prints out table contents and though the contents are the same, the bit of hex describing the nested tables are different. Example:

Reading the first nested table of the map file:

```
1   table: 0x106c5a720
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   1
8   1
9   1
```

Reading the first nested table of the manually created table:

```
1   table: 0x106c64120
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   1
8   1
9   1
```

What's going on here? The values are all identical but something strange is happening.

edit: Here's the bit of code that renders the map for reference:

```
for y=1, #map do
    for x=1, #map[y] do
      if map[y][x] == 1 then
        print("found a wall")
        love.graphics.rectangle("fill", x * 30, y * 30, 30, 30)
      elseif map[y][x] == 2 then
        print("found a button")
        love.graphics.setColor(255, 0, 0)
        love.graphics.rectangle("fill", x * 30, y * 30, 30, 30)
        love.graphics.setColor(0, 0, 255)
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to doesn't work? Do you get an error? If so, what sort of error? As to the hex bit in the description, it's table's memory address (I guess, or perhaps ID/hash) so two different table will never share the same ID, in spite of being identical in terms of contents. Have you tried iterating through both tables with ipairs to see that they are indeed identical?

Comment: Ah! Thanks for clearing up the hex thing! That solves that mystery. As far as an error, I get none. The game runs and everything, the map just doesn't render. I added the rendering code above if you want to take a look at it. It seems "map[x][y]" never equals "1". I tried printing out "map[x][y]" and it definitely equals "1" multiple times, as it should. Also when I iterate through the tables as you mentioned they still appear identical.

Comment: I suspect the problem lies within your file reading routine. As you read the file, you read characters, ie ASCII characters. So when you test an element, the element is ASCII character 1, so in fact it's equal to 0x31, not 1. Try using tonumber() on each read character.

Comment: Holy crap! That was it! Thanks so much! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading data from a text file, you are getting **strings**.
In your original `map` table you have **numbers**.
Numbers are not equal to strings.

```
assert(1 ~= '1')
```

Comment: Thanks! That turned out to be it! You arrived at the same conclusion as W.B. above.